# Unable to start AVD in Android Studio in windows 10

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I just installed android studio4.0 on windows 10. When I try to start it I get a pop-up with
The emulator process for AVD Copy_of_Pixel_3a_R was killed.
[pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbdDD.png)
This also comes in events for each attempt to start the device
Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
I reinstalled Intel HAXM but its still not working.
I also tried changing the verison of android(R,Pie)
Here is a list of SDKs
[SDK list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOzPA.png)

Answer (score 0):

In My opinion, this problem arises because the image 3а sways from play store,
try to put 3 XL or 3a XL,it helped me.